# I do not know why I have a touch indicator in my app ios

Tags: swift, debugging, xcode10

I'm developing an app with Swift in Xcode10 with multiple targets.

When I run my application there is always a blue indicator of all the events that I touch on the screen, so after uploading it to TestFlight it remains there in emulator or devices. I do not know where or how to deactivate it.

[image: image here]

Here is the list of all my dependencies, in case someone identifies if any library causes this:

[image: My podfile]

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: After viewing your image - it looks like, the image that you sent belongs to android. not to iOS

Comment: Check the following link, May be helpful: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/203044/enable-touch-indicator-for-ios-app-demo-video-recording

Comment: @AbhishekJadhav I want the indicator to disappear, I have no idea what causes it to appear

Comment: @MehulThakkar If it's ios, it's a screenshot of an iPhone X you can notice by the home button that has in the bottom

Comment: @JuniorQuevedoGutierrez is your activity indicator on viewController view?

Comment: @AbhishekJadhav  no, it's a kind of touch indicator, it always appears anywhere you press the screen is emulator, device, debug and production

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a library like [ShowTime](https://github.com/KaneCheshire/ShowTime) in your project.

In ShowTime you can allow it to only show in debug:

```
ShowTime.enabled = .debugOnly
```

Comment: It is similar, however I dont have that library installed directly. Edit the post with my podfile

Comment: You saved my day, check my code well, and an old partner had placed the same library but embedded. Thank you.